# MemoryRouter does not set search part of location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, react-router

I want to test if my component can get search part of location and transform to json for use, but when I set `initialEntries` with the querystring the search part is not changed.

```js
//My Test
render(
  <MemoryRouter inititalEntries={['/pesquisa?number=1&uf=PR']}>
    <App/>
  </MemoryRouter>
)

//My Component
const Pesquisa = (props) => {
  const { search } = props.location
  // what i want
  // search === '?number=1&uf=PR'
  // what i have
  // search === ''
}
export default withRouter(Pesquisa)

// My Container App
const App = () => 
  <div className="App">
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/pesquisa" render={props => <Pesquisa/>}/>
      </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `useLocation()` hook from react-router-dom.
You have to look at `location.search`.

Answer (score -1):

Query parameters live under match from withRouter

```
const { pesquisa } = props.match.params;
```